# Android intent empty even when data is put through

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

So here I have an intent which I use to open a new activity and push data through

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
     Intent openNav = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NavActivity.class);
     openNav.putExtra("LAT", "01");
     startActivity(openNav);
 }
    });
```

My app works fine until I try to access the data from the intent in NavActivity:

```
public class NavActivity extends Activity{
   Intent i = getIntent();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav);


if (i != null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome to NAV",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter LAT and LONG",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

So I checked to see if the intent is null, and it is each time.  Is there any way I can fix this, or something I am missing?

I have not included  a line where I .getExtras() from the intent since it crashes whenever I put that line in.  Is there any reason why this keeps on happening?

**EDIT!!! SOLUTION FOUND**
So if anyone else ever come across this problem, I found the solution to it after playing around.  For some reason, when the application opens the new activity, there is no intent available at that time so you can't use it and GET anything from that intent.

Thus, declare the intent and get values from it in the OnCreate().

Thanks a lot to all the guys who helped me, this has been an interesting journey figuring something as stupid as this out.

Comment: Could you please provide some more code? Are you sure you call `getIntent()` from your `NavActivity.java`?

Comment: u want to move next activity ?  @user3897321

Comment: I edited my code snippets and yes, I do call getIntent() in my activity.  It still remains empty though.

Comment: I move to the next activity with no problem at all, the intent that I am sending WITH data is empty even if I do put data in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In First Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, NavActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("LAT", "01");
startActivity(intent);
```

Second Activity :

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String value2 = bundle.getString("LAT");
```

Comment: I changed 'Intent openNav = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NavActivity.class);' to 'Intent openNav = new Intent(MapActivity.this, NavActivity.class);' and it is still empty.

Comment: Okay, I have added where I check my intent at the end of my question.

Comment: ok, in your NavActivity, use this 
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String value2 = bundle.getString("LAT");
and to check for value.
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: no need to create Intent i, you can just use Bundle

Comment: My application crashes once I try to get anything from the intent from the map page.  So even if I don't need to create an intent, the intent doesn't seem to have anything to get causing my application to crash.  I don't really get why since I am putting data through.

Answer (score 0):

In second activity use:-

```
public class NavActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav);

 Intent i = getIntent();
String lat= i.getStringExtra("LAT");

if (lat != null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome to NAV",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter LAT and LONG",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: The reason why I have not included the `String lat= i.getStringExtra("LAT");` in my code is because my application crashes when I introduce it. I want to know why that happens.

Comment: did u even tried my code or went through it properly?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code but you basically copied my code and added one line - the one line that was causing my whole application to crash.  Yes it is in the on create exactly where it should be, but for some reason it kept on crashing even though I used an intent. So when I used a bundle in the onCreate() it did work.  I have no idea why though.